# How to unique elements of each cell vector?

Tags: matlab, vector, cell

Suppose I have ten cell vectors, `c{1},c{2},...,c{10}`, if I want to extract the unique elements of each cell vector at the same time (in a vectorized manner), how can I do it? I tried to use `unique(c)`, but it did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have unique elements of each cell then you have to apply unique on each cell, like `unique(C{1})`, `unique(C{2})` etc. This can be achieved by using `cellfun`.

```
uniqueCellArray=cellfun(@unique,yourCellArray,'UniformOutput',false);
```

If your cell array contains a matrix then you may want to use the option `'rows'`. If you don't want to sort the outpur of `unique`, you may want to use the option `'stable'`. You can modify the above statement as follows:

```
uniqueTestCell=cellfun(@(x) (unique(x,'rows','stable')),testCell,'UniformOutput',false);
```